# Using variable as selected value in dropdown that is created from tables

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have spent alot of time using StackOverflow and made lots of progress on my current project but I have hit a roadblock that I cannot find the solution for anywhere so I figured it is about time I reach out for help.

- Website is a user profile type website
- Each user sets up an individual account then can navigate to a specific page (update) where they can select things like their sex (m/f), occupation, age range etc... all from drop down menus. The drop down options are all pulled from a table (1 table for each category).
- After they complete their information selection the data is stored in a table called 'users' and there is no issue retrieving that data or writing it under normal circumstances
- The problem is if the user navigates back to the update page I cannot have it so the default value for each of the dropdown menus is the one that matches their value stored in the users table

Below is the code I use to generate one of the dropdowns.

```
<?
      $query = "SELECT sex FROM pupsex"; 
      $sex = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

      $sexdown = "<select name='sex'>";
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sex)) {
      $sexdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['sex']}'echo selected=$sexd>{$row['sex']}</option>";
      }
      $sexdown .= "\r\n</select>";
      echo $sexdown;
```

?>

Prior to displaying the the dropdowns in the code I use the logged in user and retrieve all their specific information and insert them into variables so they are ready to use as the default values.

Thanks in advance, if you need more information feel free to ask.

Comment: So is `$sexd` the logged in user's `sex`?

Comment: @Sean, yes the $sexd is the users sex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to adjust the while loop in your dropdown generate code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sex)) {
   if ($sexd == $row['sex']) {
           $selected = " selected ";
       } else {
           $selected = "";
       }
      $sexdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['sex']}' {$selected} >{$row['sex']}</option>";
  }
```

Comment: thanks so much. That seems to have fixed the glitch I was facing.